# how to filter table column id into corresponding name directly with a sql query

Tags: c#, sql

I have this table where columns correspond to names:

i.e. 11 = first, 12 = second, 13 = third..

```
COLUMNID(string)  starttime(string) endtime(string) 

11                 20111203123132    20101203143239
11                 20101203143156     20101203143322
11                     ...               ...
12
12
13
14
16
17
18
18
```

I would need a query to give me names instead of ID

```
COLUMNAME(string)  starttime(string) endtime(string) 
FIRST                 20111203123132    20101203143239
FIRST                 20101203143156     20101203143322
FIRST                    ...               ...
FIRST
FIRST
SECOND
SECOND
THIRD
...
```

SOLUTION:

SELECT ID, USERID, ( CASE 
                     WHEN SUBSTR(USERID,1,4) LIKE 'CC0%' THEN 'ADMIN'
                     WHEN SUBSTR(USERID,1,4) LIKE 'CC1%' THEN 'THEO'
                     WHEN SUBSTR(USERID,1,4) LIKE 'CC12%' THEN 'PAT'
                     WHEN SUBSTR(USERID,1,4) LIKE 'CC13%' THEN 'DOUG'
                     WHEN SUBSTR(USERID,1,4) LIKE 'C22%' THEN 'PHIL'
                     WHEN SUBSTR(USERID,1,4) LIKE 'K15%' THEN 'SONIA'
                     WHEN SUBSTR(USERID,1,4) LIKE 'k16%' THEN 'JEAN'
                     WHEN SUBSTR(USERID,1,4) LIKE 'P58%' THEN 'FAB'
                     WHEN SUBSTR(USERID,1,4) LIKE 'P9%'  THEN 'LOG'
                     ELSE 'N/A' 
                     END ) USERNAME
FROM LOG_HISTORY

Comment: And what you have tried so far? Did you encounter some specific problems you would like to ask about?

Comment: Seconded; however, as a starting point - look into SQL "join"

Comment: i can filter in the code with switch and all the cases and i hate that.

Comment: Could you expand on your table definitions more?

Comment: Are those `first` for 11, `second` for 12 etc. stored in a table somewhere?? Then it would be a simple JOIN lookup query... no messy `CASE` statements needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what database type you are targetting.  If you are targeting SQL Server, I would suggest exploring something like this

```
SELECT Name = 
   CASE COLUMNID
      WHEN '11' THEN First 
      WHEN '12' THEN Second
   END,
   starttime, endtime
FROM yourtable
```

You may want to look at your database design.  I'm not sure what you curently have is the best to achieve the result you seem to want.  Is there a reason starttime and endtime columns are strings instead of datetime?

Edit : Modified Query to match question update

Comment: thanks alot as the case statement lead me to the right search

Comment: You should post the solution you used (because it sounds like you didnt use what I suggested, it just helped you find it) so that others with the same problem can see what you did.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not have a function to convert numbers into ordinals.

Check [this](http://www.techknowsolve.com/blog/?p=36) for an example on how to write your custom one.